# How to show a QImage without copying in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qimage

I have my own image class containing an unsigned char array with RGB values. I would like to show images stored in this class, without copying them, in a QGraphicsScene. I can make an QImage with

```
QImage image(data, width, height, width * 3, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

without copying my image. How can I show image in a QGraphicsScene without a deep copy of data?

Comment: Why do you think that such an image will make a deep copy? It won't - unless you can point to code within Qt that forces a deep copy.

Comment: He have to convert QImage to QPixmap first.

Comment: The line above leads to a shallow copy. But I absolulty don't know what happens after this line internally in qt. E.g. my next line atm is `QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = scene_.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));` and it seems to be not even documented, if scene_ has the ownership of item. Probably it is so.

Comment: A QPixmap object will be created, with a copy of the data, and you can delete your data (ar a QImage object) from the memory. It should be save.

Comment: It doesn't matter who has the ownership of what, both `QPixmap` and `QImage` are implicitly shared.

Comment: If you look at `QPixmap`'s implementation on the raster backend, it's just `QImage` :)

Comment: @KubaOber He created QImage without copying the data from the instance of his class. But calling QPixmap::fromImage creates a copy of data. Not exactly the copy, but at least reserved a new memory for storing image data in the way optimized for displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default, raster paint engine/backend, the top-level widget's contents are stored as a `QImage`. Drawing a `QImage` (and a `QPixmap`, too) on it is quick and doesn't involve copies. The `QPixmap`, with the raster backend, is simply internally a `QImage` that has the same format as that of the backing store. The pixmap generally doesn't represent any native resource handle - since you are using a raster backend unless you ask for something else explicitly.

So what you would wish to do is to directly `drawImage` from your source image, within a `QGraphicsItem::paint` implementation. What really happens behind the scenes is the `paint` gets executed on the backing store - a `QImage`, and that's fast and efficient. The `QPainter` that you use operates on a `QImage`!

All you have to do is to implement a `QGraphicsImageItem` akin to `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. No copying and no format conversion will be involved as long as your source image has the same format as the image backing the top-level window. And how would you know that? Just ask the backing store about what format it's in.

```
QImage::Format backingStoreFormat(QWidget * widget) {
  auto store = dynamic_cast<QImage*>(widget->backingStore()->paintDevice())
  return store ? store->format() : QImage::Format_Invalid;
}
```

I leave the implementation of `QGraphicsImageItem` to the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying images QPixmap is a proper class. QGraphicsScene pdovides a method only for a QPixmap.

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem * QGraphicsScene::addPixmap(const QPixmap & pixmap)
```

However, QPixmap is an optimized class for displaying images, so it can't be created with existing block of memory. So if you intend to display your memory data as an image in QGraphicsScene, it seems to be not possible (with reasonable effort).

Why do you concern about copying a data from your class into QPixmap? Is there a prove, that it will be a performance bottle-neck?

If not, either you convert your class directly to a QPixmap or use QPixmap::fromImage().
Add yout image with e.g.:

```
myScene->addPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(myImage) );
```

Comment: Sorry for this beginner's explanation. According to your comment you new it obviously :-)