# Rendering Image filters

Tags: qt, filter, effects, qgraphicsview

I am using QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene framework to display an HD image (and some overlaying items). Image will appear scaled down but I need the full resolution as the user is able to zoom in to parts of the image.

I need to apply some simple filters to the image like display the Red channel. How can I apply the filters to only the visible part of the image? For example if the original image size is 1920x1080 displayed scaled down to 720x480 I want to apply the filter only to the 720x480 image.

This will greatly reduce the CPU cycles used to apply filters.

Comment: You'd need to reimplement the item's `paint` method.

Comment: But how I will get the pixel value so I  extract the red value? And what about the case that I need more advanced filters that needs the histogram of the image?

Comment: Under the wraps, what you're painting on is nothing but a `QImage`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32103860/1329652), and [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18724391/1329652).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I use the original QImage I will still need to process it in full resolution. I found a good solution to sub-class QGraphicsEffect and apply that on the view. This will be applied at the on-screen resolution and works perfectly. But caused a new issue - I have some overlay items on the image and the effect paints them too. Pity problem still not solved.